# Tail and grep docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, grep, tail

How can I both tail and grep Docker logs? I've tried the following:

```
sudo docker logs -f my_container | grep foo
```

This should tail all lines with `foo` from the container's logs, but instead shows everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
sudo docker logs -f my_container &> log.log & tail -f log.log | grep foo
```

`docker logs -f my_container &> log.log` tails all the containers logs while also outputting to file `log.log`. In parallel, which is what the `&` by itself does, `tail -f log.log | grep foo` tails that file and greps, which a common way to grep tailed output.

The downside is that file `log.log` is created, but there was no other way to do this.